# ChildView of ExpandableListView changes the selection of radio button in android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-radiobutton

I am having two radio buttons in child of every group. But when group expand and collapse radio button selection changes its position. I set Images of the problem.

When group expand and i change the selection of radio buttons as shown in below image

[image: When group expand and i change the selection of radio buttons]

When i collapse group and then expand it, Child view change the radio button selection position as shown in below image

[image: When i collapse group and then expand it, Child view change the radio button selection position]

Cant understand what to do here?